# for loop is not working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Can someone explain why this `for...loop` doesn't work? (it should write all checked checkboxes but it writes only the last checked)

```
function Matula() 
{
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var y = document.createElement("p");
    var g = document.createTextNode("Vasa pizza bude obsahovat:");
    y.appendChild(g);
    x.appendChild(y);
    var swag = document.forms["lol"].matej.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < swag; i++) 
    {
        if (document.forms["lol"].matej[i].checked) 
        {
            var torko = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var q = document.createElement("p");
            var w = document.createTextNode(document.forms["lol"].matej[i].value);
            q.appendChild(w);

            torko.appendChild(q);
            return mocny = 0
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: After 6 questions it is time to learn how to format your code. Select your code -> ctrl+k

Comment: @PeeHaa I didn't know about the keyboard shortcut, nice!

Comment: Also, those variable names are terrible. I have no idea what this is supposed to do.

Comment: When you output the `document.forms["lol"].matej.length` does it show any value?

Comment: You can use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`

Comment: Also can you show us the basic HTML structure of your form?

Comment: You're returning inside your if, which is inside that for loop. That doesn't seem right. Always try and place the return at the last line of your function, that will prevent many errors.

Comment: `return mocny = 0` is ALWAYS going to return the same value making ALL of the rest of your code irrelevant..

Answer (score 3):

```
return mocny = 0
```

exits the function , so `for` it loops only once, put it outside `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

There is a return statement in your if block. This will essentially break the loop after the first time it goes inside the if. So that means only value of one check box will be print out.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea as to what that is supposed to do as it is awfuly confusing will all those var names. But your return inside your if, which inside your for loop, doesn't seem right.

You should put that at the last line of your function.

Comment: Ok, so you are telling me you downvoted the other two answers because those weren't yours?

Comment: Why reply, in that way, to my initial comment as of why I was downvoted?

Comment: You were down voted, you were angry. You are up voted, so you are (happy)

Comment: I'm sorry but it's clearly saying that the return statement should not be there, and if you read the comments on the answer you'll notice that that was the problem. And I'm commenting, besides answering, about his code, not the way he's asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner code could look like this:

```
function Matula() {
    var body = document.body;
    addParagraph(body, "Vasa pizza bude obsahovat:");

    var allToppings = document.forms["lol"].matej;
    var toppingsCount = allToppings.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < toppingsCount; i++) {
        if (allToppings[i].checked) {
            addParagraph(body,allToppings[i].value);
        }
    }
}

function addParagraph(body, textToAdd) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(textToAdd);
    body.appendChild(y);
}
```

*Typed off my head, might contain typos*
Makes it so much easier to read. Btw. Bracket position does make a difference (it isn't Java), so keep it on the same line (Google the reasons) Does it work for you?